# Having trouble nesting a link within a link in HAML

Tags: html, ruby, haml, nested

I'm having trouble with HAML nesting a link within another link. The indentation is completely correct in the HAML, but the HTML is being output very wrong.

The original HAML code:

```
.item
  =link_to page_path do
    .item-info
      %h3 Item name
      =link_to 'Link', different_page_path
```

When I view the HTML in Chrome's inspect element, this is what I get:

```
<a href="/page"></a>
<div class="item-info">
  <a href="/page">
    <h3>Item name</h3>
  </a>
  <a href="/different_page">Link</a>
</div>
```

But when I view the source, it show's up correctly, but is still messed up when viewing the page:

```
<a href="/page">
  <div class='item-info'>
    <h3>Item name</h3>
    <a href="/different_page">Link</a>
  </div>
</a>
```

I'm at a loss and any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to put a link inside of a link?

Comment: I'm trying to have a larger container that serves as a link, but also containing a link within that would go to a different page. But I discovered that browser rules will not allow a link to be nested within a link. Not sure why, but I guess that's how it is.

Comment: Well, what would you expect to happen when you click on one link that's inside of another link?

Comment: It actually works when using basic HTML http://jsfiddle.net/4gUvj/. But it's not W3C standards compliant.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want a link within a link you could use haml directly instead of the rails (or what framework you are using) method link_to:

```
.item
  %a{ :href => '/page' }
    .item-info
      %h3 Item name
      %a{ :href => '/different_page' } Link
```

link_to is helping you to do the right thing visavi the browser as discussed above. It may be good to realize that this is not a haml issue but rather the link_to implementation.

UPDATE: clarification - it will still not be rendered nicely by the browser but the markup produced will be as asked for.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that this method doesn't work as well. I actually started using HAML for the container. The browser still renders it incorrectly.

Comment: yes and I tried to reference that discussion in my answer. Editing answer to make it clearer.